# Get only one argument from URL

Tags: php

I have an URL like so:

`http://local.mywebsite.com/index.php?p=edit_entry?id=3`

and I want to retrieve only the `p` argument which value in this case above is "edit
_entry".

I have written:

```
$p = $_GET['p'];
echo $p;
```

But when I do so I get the value `edit_entry?id=3`

What should I do? I just want to retrieve `edit_entry`

Comment: Try putting & between entry? and id=3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an invalid URL. `?` signifies the START of the query parameters, it's not a seperator BETWEEN parameters. You use `&` for that:

```
http://local.mywebsite.com/index.php?p=edit_entry&id=3
                                                 ^---
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the url should be:

```
http://local.mywebsite.com/index.php?p=edit_entry&id=3
                                                 ^ ampersand
```

It should be `&` instead of `?`

Answer (score 1):

`?` is the delimiter which separates the URL from the PARAMETERS.

The parameters are separated by an ampersand `&`.

So you have to use `index.php?param1=something&param2=something&etc=etc`